# Adding multiple rows of information from a database to a text box

Tags: c#, sql, database, forms

Thanks for reviewing my question. Basically, in my form... The manager can set a reminder to an employee, so when the employee logs into my form... it comes up with a reminder from the manager.

Trouble is, the data contains multiple reminders from the same user but when I add them to a text box I get this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Sequence contains more than one element

my code:

```
                System.Windows.Forms.Form f = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Login"];
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(((Login)f).idTb.Text);
            SundownDatabaseEntities4 db = new SundownDatabaseEntities4();
            var getrecord = db.Reminders.Where(a => a.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();

            reminderTb.Text = Convert.ToString(getrecord.Reminder1);
```

How do I add multiple elements to a text box? Could I use a list box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to append multiple different strings to a single textbox, which in this case i would use the appendText() extension on the textbox to add multiple strings. You could also use the ListBox if you would like. I would set the Source to the data you are sending it for ease of use.

Here is a link to the append text function
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a link to how to set-up a source for a listbox
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx

## Edit

To add on since it was something else causing the issue I would use:

```
List<object> objects = Enumerable.Select(i => i.id == id);
```

Here is a link to the msdn for more information
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx

## Edit 2

After finally getting my VS up to date and playing around i think the easiest thing you can do here is:

```
db.Reminders.ForEach(reminder => {if(reminder.Id == id){ reminderTb.AppendText(Convert.ToString(reminder.Reminder1));  }})
```

You might need to adjust accordingly to your specific code not sure if i have your class structure right, but this will look through the array of reminders, look and on that specific id it will append the text to the text box with what I imagine is what you wanted based off your code and the class structure i saw. this should work since you are manually going through the array and adding the text.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. This line: 'var getrecord = db.Reminders.Where(a => a.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();' seems to be the problem, it's looking for 1 id and there's multiple of  the same id in the database, any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: List<object> objects = Enumerable.Select(i => i.id == id); doesn't work I get an error: No overload for method... take 1 argument. Thanks!